# Getting stackoverflow when calling findAll() method of spring jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

I am using Entitylistener for one of my entity. @PostUpdate() calls repo.findAll() method, which is causing stackoverflow. It stuck in the infinite loop.
Please tell me, how can I solve this. Similar kind of issue is reported here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/732 (formerly DATAJPA-325)

Comment: It is not similar, it is exactly that issue. The issue explains the problem quite well in my opinion. What else do you need?

Comment: I tried @Cacheable, it worked but I need recently saved data which I am not getting.